# Having Issues with setting up site/start page with Angular HelloWorld project in VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, angular

I know the VS Code is the tool most seen in Angular demos and I've tried them but I was going through a YouTube demo on using Visual Studio to develop a Hello World Angular app.I started out using NPM START to run the app then was following the instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMjN-NXjia4&feature=youtu.be&t=204) to use the Visual Studio Start button to initiate the app.

The app was sometimes rerunning and sometimes not. I was thinking it had something to do with the startup folder but now I wish that I would have modified by startup page instead.

Here's what my folder structure looks like:

[image: SolutionsExplorer]

Anyways, I first I started messing with the application root URL. I tried changing it from

> http://localhost:61539

to

> http://localhost:61539/src

and some other values too. I confirmed that i wanted to create a virtual folder and played around entering multiple values. As a result, I noticed that my IISExpress icon in the tray started to show all of the URLS  that I had entered

[image: IISExpressSites]

I wanted to try an undo these virtual folders that I created but I didn't know where they were stored. Finally, I saw that the last path that I specify is stored in the VS *Project* file but I don't know where all of the other sites are stored. I'd like to delete them. Is there some IIS Express config file?

The whole problem started when I was trying to get the initial the web page to come up and I was getting a "Forbidden" error. Now I think that it could possible be solve by setting my initial page to src/index.html, although the YouTube video didn't mention it.

Now, every time I hit the start button to run the web app, the following URL is displayed with an extra trailing slash after the html page name.

```
http://localhost:61539/src/index.html/
```

and I still get the forbidden error.

- **Question**

**So, how do I clean up my IIS Sites that I don't need and set my startup params so that the web page comes up and displays index.html?**

[image: ProjProps]

Comment: I just changed the port number in the Project URL and the Override application URL and everything looks OK. I found the Virtual folders specified in \Angular2Demo\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"

Comment: Does my Project properties look OK? for example, my Start Page? Is this typical that the start page is not at the root level?